# Error in C# threading application

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have created 4 projects to online examination time monitoring

1. ASP.NET application to examination
2. Class Library for Business Process and Data Access
3. Class Library to database execution
4. Windows form application to monitor examination time

in Windows form application I use threads for monitor when new exam start and I want to indicate notification before 5 munites to end the examination.

when using visual studio for debug the app its not getting any error. but manually click the .exe file and run the application it getting an error "application stopped working"

This is my code for windows form application

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Thread t;
    Thread t1;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        fillList();           
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        t= new Thread(()=>getTrigger());
        t1 = new Thread(() => TimeOption());
        t.Start();
        t1.Start();
       // getTrigger();
    }


    private  void getTrigger()
    {

        int temp = StudentExamDB.getPendingCount();

        while (true)
        {
            if (temp != StudentExamDB.getPendingCount())
            {
                fillList();
                temp = StudentExamDB.getPendingCount();

            }
        }

    }
    List<string> added = new List<string>();
    private void TimeOption()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            DataTable dt = StudentExamDB.getFinishingList();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {

                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["enrollmentid"].Value.ToString() == dr["enrollmentid"].ToString())
                        {
                            if (added.Contains(dr["enrollmentid"].ToString()))
                            {
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipTitle = "Ending Some Examinations";
                                notifyIcon1.BalloonTipText = "click here to show more details about examination time";
                                notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(5000);

                                added.Add(dr["enrollmentid"].ToString());



                            }
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;



                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }            
    }

    private void fillList()
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = StudentExamDB.getPendingList();
        }
        catch
        {
        }            
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        t.Abort();
        t1.Abort();
    }

    private void setToFinishedToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StudentExamDB.updateStatus(int.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["enrollmentid"].Value.ToString()));
            fillList();

        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Can you make your winforms app log the exception stack trace and details ?

Comment: Its not getting any exception when debugging in VisualStudio...

Answer (score 4):

Are you aware of what this does?

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
```

You're *explicitly* turning off checks for what you're doing wrong. That suggests that you *know* you shouldn't be modifying the UI on a non-UI thread, but you're doing it anyway. If you didn't have that line of code, you certainly *would* get exceptions when running in Visual Studio.

That's at least *one* of the problems. Your `TimeOption` method is running on a non-UI thread, but it's modifying the UI. Just don't do that. There are various other options, including `BackgroundWorker` and `Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke`.

Then...

- You've got tight loops in both `TimeOption` and `getTrigger`. Basically you're going to be pounding the database hard, forever. That's a really bad idea. You should *at least* have a delay between iterations
- You've got empty `catch` blocks all over the place: `catch {}`. That's basically claiming that whatever goes wrong, you're fine - you can just keep going and ignore it, without even logging what's happened. Don't do that.
- You're using `Thread.Abort` to kill your threads. Don't do that. In this case it would be pretty simple to use a volatile `bool` field indicating when you want to finish, and check it on each iteration of the loop.

I *suspect* the problems are due to your inappropriate access to the UI from a different thread - but I can't say for sure. Fix all of the above and you'll have a much better codebase to then diagnose any problems which still remain.

Comment: +1 Basically, your (OP) code is saying "I'm going to do a bunch of stuff totally incorrect." You shouldn't wonder why it doesn't work.